# How to run a bash file with no extension in Python

Tags: python, bash, python-3.x

I was wondering how I could use the script from this page in Python:

http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/textcleaner/index.php

When downloading it, there is no extension. I tried renaming it to "textcleaner.sh" and run the following:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.check_call(['textcleaner.sh', '-g', '-e', 'normalize', 'input_image.jpg', 'output_image.jpg'])
```

But I get this error when doing so:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ikdem/PycharmProjects/McAffeeeeeee/bash test.py", line 11, in <module>
    subprocess.check_call(['textcleaner.sh', '-g', '-e', 'normalize', 'opl-small-1.jpg', 'output.jpg'])
  File "C:\Users\ikdem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 579, in check_call
    retcode = call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ikdem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 560, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\ikdem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\ikdem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a windows system, the default shell isn't `bash`. Renaming to `.sh` won't help, and windows tries to `execv` your file, which isn't a Windows executable, which explains the (bad) error message from Windows.

The best thing you could do would be to:

- download & install MSYS2 ex in `C:\MSYS2`
- change your line as follows:

code:

```
subprocess.check_call([r'C:\MSYS2\bin\sh','-c','textcleaner.sh', '-g', '-e', 'normalize', 'input_image.jpg', 'output_image.jpg'])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this seemed to make the error dissapear. Getting another error now but I'll try to make it work!

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not have support for parsing a Unix-style shebang within its binary loader, and will require you to invoke a copy of `sh.exe` or  `bash.exe` instead, passing it the path to the script followed by arguments to the script. You can typically find these executables as part of a MinGW or MSYS installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can run my script on Windows, only if you use a Unix terminal, such as installing Cygwin or using Windows 10 built in Unix and install ImageMagick.

If you run Python from a unix terminal on Windows, it can be run. See http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=32920, where I run a simple Imagemagick command.

You can run it natively on Windows using a version of that script converted into Magick.Net. See https://github.com/dlemstra/FredsImageMagickScripts.NET

Usage of my script in either form for commercial purposes will require obtaining a license. Usage otherwise is free.